# When to use the preprocessor to define functions in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

When should I use the **C** preprocessor to define a function? Here's a quick example:

```
#define isUnderscore(ch) ((ch) == '_')
```

Over this:

```
// just to make the bool more clear.
typedef enum {
    false, true
} bool;

bool isUnderscore(char x) {
    return x == '_';
}
```

This may be a stupid question, but I can't find any results from a quick Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally use the preprocessor if you want to discard type-safety. `isUnderscore` as a macro will accept any type for `ch` for which `==` makes sense.

As a rule of thumb, don't use the preprocessor unless absolutely necessary: debugging functions implemented as preprocessor macros is difficult.

(Remember that function overloading is not available in C).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from C99 you could write it as `inline` function:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

inline bool isUnderscore(char x) {
    return x == '_';
}
```

This gives you both safety and type-checking of normal functions as well as efficiency of function-like macros (though there is not guarantee on that).

From N1570 (C11 draft) `6.7.4/6` *Function specifiers* (with emphasis mine):

> A function declared with an `inline` function specifier is an *inline
>   function*. Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to
>   the function be as fast as possible.<sup>138)</sup> The extent to
>   which such suggestions **are effective is
>   implementation-defined**.<sup>139)</sup>

Comment: So is the inline keyword and optimisation here? Since I remember reading that the compiler chooses when to inline a function.

Comment: Yup, it's for guidance only; rather like `register`.

Comment: @reefourann: Added excerpt from Standard. In practive some compilers (e.g. GCC) are able to warn if such function is not effectively inlined.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is if you can do something in the language itself rather than the preprocessor then you should.

A few decades ago there might have been a performance improvement where the macro would be inline, but any compiler that you're likely to use will be do these trivial optimisations.